# How to pass a string to a var without escape symbol in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I hope to pass the string `{"name":"My Settings 1"}` to a var aa

I have to write it using the code  `var aa=" {\"name\":\"My Settings 1\"} "`

Is there a simple way in Kotlin when I use Android Studio 3.0 ?

I know `<![CDATA[...]]>` is good for XML content

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Escaping special chars in regular `String`s, like in your example, is what has to be done with Java and also Kotlin:

```
"{\"name\":\"My Settings 1\"}"
```

Kotlin offers raw Strings to evade this. In these raw `String`s there's no need to escape special chars, which shows the following:

```
 """{"name":"My Settings 1"}"""
```

Raw Strings are delimited by a triple quote (`"""`).
Read the docs [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-literals).

Answer (score 12):

The simplest thing you can do in Kotlin is use [raw strings](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-literals) with triple quote marks:

```
val a = """{"name":"My Settings 1"}"""
```

---

For a tooling solution instead of a language solution (so this works both in Kotlin and Java), you can use [language injection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html) in Android Studio or IntelliJ.

1. Create a string, and invoke intention actions on it with Alt + Enter. Select `Inject language or reference`, and then `JSON`.

   [image: Inject language or reference]

   [image: JSON]
2. Use Alt + Enter again, and choose `Edit JSON Fragment`.

   [image: Edit JSON Fragment]
3. Edit the raw JSON in the panel that appears on the bottom, and IntelliJ will automatically mirror its contents into the string, escaping any characters that have to be escaped.

   [image: Screenshot of the JSON fragment editor]